# STRIPE Integration Nodejs + React. Queries

Tags: node.js, reactjs, stripe-payments

I am new to Stripe.
I am using React(front-end) and Node(backend).
Using new **Payment Method APIs**, instead of **Sources APIs**.
Here are my queries.

1. How can a user select a saved card while legacy checkout?
2. Before that how to list saved user cards.
3. Are there any other payment methods for paying for a subscription during a legacy checkout.
   Here's my API code for third question

```
stripe(secretKey).checkout.sessions.create({
      mode: 'subscription',
      payment_method_types: ['card'],
      customer: id,
      line_items: [
        {
          price: JSON.parse(args.plan_id), // plan_id = plan to be subscribed
          quantity: 1,
        },
      ],
      success_url: `${successUrl[0]}?gateway_id=${args.gateway_id}&session_id={CHECKOUT_SESSION_ID}`,
      cancel_url: args.cancel_url,
    })
```

(August-28 2020)Query-4: Which is better to use- Stripe Legacy Checkout OR Stripe Elements and why?

Comment: You need to provide much more detail about what you're doing or trying to do. Legacy checkout doesn't support saved payment methods. You can list saved payment methods any way you like. Retrieve them from your server, show them in your UI. I don't understand question 3. Legacy checkout is deprecated and doesn't work with payment methods at all.

Comment: Hi Nolan, Thanks for the quick reply. I am working on a basic Stripe subscribe/unsubscribe integration. In the third question, I meant to say during a subscribe checkout, can we display other payment method types like alipay or giropay. I have added backend code above for the third question.